# Ruby OpenSSL::Cipher giving different result Tripple DES in CBC Mode

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I need to encrypt data with double-length Triple-DES (TDEA) symmetric key in CBC mode. I am using Ruby OpenSSl::Cipher. But it give different result as compared to BP-tool Cryptographic calculator and EMV DES Calculator. Following is my code

Can any body help me why my results are different? I have check online tool also to verify my result.

http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/?key=2315208C9110AD402315208C9110AD40&iv=0000000000000000&input=20205A4F534135366461746574696D653D32303138313032343130303332333B6578706972793D313232323B70616E3D343233363031373839303132333435362121212121212121&mode=cbc&action=Encrypt&output=20205A4F534135366461746574696D653D32303138313032343130303332333B6578706972793D313232323B70616E3D343233363031373839303132333435362121212121212121

It give same result as BP-tool.

```
flavour = 'des-ede3-cbc'
# key and input text are in hexadecimal  
key = "2315208C9110AD402315208C9110AD40"
iv = "0000000000000000"
input_text = "2020205a4f534135366461746574696d653d32303138313032343130303332333b6578706972793d313232323b70616e3d343233363031373839303132333435362121212121212121"
begin
  c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new flavour
  c.encrypt
  c.key = key
  c.iv = iv
  str = input_text
  enc = c.update(str) + c.final
  puts "#{flavour} gives us #{enc.unpack('H*').first.upcase}"
rescue => e
    puts "#{flavour} didn't work because #{e.message}"
end
```

```
Result:
8AF0D655A844EC016E171F1892188DD5C77E6F76D79A4582313D2415D9AD6944E16C7CA680CCD0C251BA8921E7C35153F345126A89ECCD68E4B0485FFDCDA778DBBE32B38451A59AFA443A96C46E30BD7CE983078EA40F8F0196C607FF537E5A36B910A40C3B0DB8C42BD2AB135928B0BDDF6DC85CF516EACCD14E0C21B93CE428A9E4F78A13AE9834966B41C4C1835B1910BE5716D117F7

The expected result should be:
4A9E9B245BBDC16D76998143CB6FC1C2B8780539C1C9A100AEC3D745B8BF00DF43A4B51A29A6205845E510E18E26AB940152F90F12E86543A9E5239B30DFDBCD8D3FCDB65F603979
```

Comment: `c.key = key` returns `ArgumentError: key must be 24 bytes`. Please provide a valid example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your expected results, you need to adjust your code so that OpenSSL actually knows that you are using hex-encoded data. Since OpenSSL deals with plain bytes anyway, you thus need to encode your hex string to raw bytes first:

```
key = ["2315208C9110AD402315208C9110AD40"].pack('H*')
iv = ["0000000000000000"].pack('H*')
input_text = ["2020205a4f534135366461746574696d653d32303138313032343130303332333b6578706972793d313232323b70616e3d343233363031373839303132333435362121212121212121"].pack('H*')
```

After that, you need to chose the right encryption algorithm. There are multiple distinct flavours of 3DES which (among other details) differ in the expected key length. Since you are dealing with a 16 byte key, it appears you are using what OpenSSL calls `des-ede-cbc`

```
flavour = 'des-ede-cbc'
```

These adjustments alone should normally be enough to cause the same result as you would see on the website you linked to. However, for some reason unknown to me, they silently change the input data before actually encrypting it.

The specific rules they use are unknown to me but to get the same ciphertext output as the website, you need to remove any trailing exclamation marks and remove a leading space character from your input string.

```
input_text # packed as you provided it originally
# => "   ZOSA56datetime=20181024100323;expiry=1222;pan=4236017890123456!!!!!!!!"

# remove trailing exclamation marks
input_text = input_text.sub(/!*$/, '') 
# remove the first character
input_text = input_text[1..-1]
```

Finally, you can now encrypt your "improved" `input_text`:

```
begin
  c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(flavour)
  c.encrypt
  c.key = key
  c.iv = iv
  enc = c.update(input_text) + c.final
  puts "#{flavour} gives us #{enc.unpack('H*').first.upcase}"
rescue => e
  puts "#{flavour} didn't work because #{e.message}"
end
```

This should result in almost the expected cipher text.

It only slightly differs at the final block of 8 bytes though. I assume the website uses some strange non-standard padding (which is required to ensure the input text can be divided into full 8 byte chunks) which results in the final block being different.

In any case, you can decrypt the result (as well as the "expected" ciphertext form the website with this code:

```
flavour = 'des-ede-cbc'
key = ["2315208C9110AD402315208C9110AD40"].pack('H*')
iv = ["0000000000000000"].pack('H*')
encrypted = ["4A9E9B245BBDC16D76998143CB6FC1C2B8780539C1C9A100AEC3D745B8BF00DF43A4B51A29A6205845E510E18E26AB940152F90F12E86543A9E5239B30DFDBCD8D3FCDB65F603979"].pack('H*')

c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(flavour)
c.decrypt
c.key = key
c.iv = iv

decrypted = c.update(encrypted)
```

How to get the padding right to match the result from the website will be left as an exercise to the reader :) Unfortunately, I have not found any documentation or source code for their tool.

In any case, please note that 3DES is an incredibly outdated encryption algorithm which is not considered secure anymore. Unless you have to actually use 3DES, you should use a more secure algorithm.

The libsodium project provides hardened implementations of secure algorithms for encryption and signing which can form a valid and secure basis for your desired protocol. There are Ruby bindings available with the [rbnacl](https://github.com/crypto-rb/rbnacl) gem.